# vc++ failed to convert difference of unsigned long long to double

Tags: c++, visual-c++

following code in vc++2017:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    unsigned long long i = 0, j = 1;

    double d = i - j;
    cout << d << endl;
}
```

result is `1.84467e+19`

is it a bug?

my vc++2017: Version 15.1(26403.7)

Comment: Unsigned arithmetic *wraps* when there is an over- or under-flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()` returns 18446744073709551615, so VS is correct.

You might want to remove `unsigned` before `long long`.

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> Unsigned integer arithmetic is always performed modulo 2<sup>n</sup>
>   where n is the number of bits in that particular integer. E.g. for
>   unsigned int, adding one to UINT_MAX gives ​0​, and subtracting one
>   from ​0​ gives UINT_MAX.

Comment: Difference of unsigned ints might be negative.

Comment: @l111 The result of unsigned arithmetic, when both operands are unsigned, is also unsigned.

Comment: @l111 compiler has no chance to know your intent, so it will not convert argument on his own.

Comment: Yola, Some programmer dude, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**No, this is not a bug. Try to move to a mindset where in the vast majority of cases, the issue is not with the compiler.**

`i - j` is `0 - 1` which evaluates to `-1` **with type** `unsigned long long` (since both arguments are `unsigned long long` types).

That is defined to be `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()`.

When converting that to a `double` (which is standardised by IEEE754 on that platform), you'll get some precision loss (you are converting something that requires 64 bits to represent into a type with a 52 bit mantissa): the result will be correct to about 15 decimal significant figures, thereby accounting for your output.